# Filter a measure - SAP Analysis for Office

Tags: excel, vba, business-objects

I am wondering, how do I filter a measure in analysis for office. I tried intuitively to use the function SAPsetfilter, but it's not working.

```
Dim lResult 
lResult = Application.Run("SAPSetFilter", "DS_1", _
    "4MSJ6WTDN3X6N2T0U5L4BHCGX")
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Thank you!

p.s. enterprise ID retrieved with sapgetdata, so it's correct.

Comment: Please give more detail. What do you have and what results do you need ? what filter are you using?

Comment: I am using Analysis for Office, so I have my BO queries within Excel. I most queries, I have several measures and I would like to be able to use VBA to filter one or a few, in order to show the appropriate result.

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution for this? I have the same problem, that the SAPSetFilter API call will always return a 0 (Call failed), no matter what combination of API Parameters i choose for SAPSetFilter.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify a dimension to be filtered and the member to filter on. For example:

```
lResult= Application.Run("SAPSetFilter", "DS_1", "0SOLD_TO__0COUNTRY", "CA;US;DE", "INPUT_STRING")
```

With this example, you set the filter for dimension 0SOLD_TO__0COUNTRY of data source DS_1 to the countries USA, Canada and Germany using member format INPUT_STRING.

Go to the help guide and search for API - there is lots of useful into in there
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to filter the data with measures. Just filter using the technical name of the member. You can find the technical name in the properties under the analysis ribbon.

For example: `Application.Run("SAPSetFilter", "DS_1","Technical name of the dimension", "technical name of the member of the measure" , "INPUT_STRING")`